# How to access a node inside CDATA with Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, xml, cdata

Given a xml

```
<xml>
<![CDATA[<myNode>aaa</myNode><anotherNode>bbb</anotherNode>]]>
</xml>
```

How to access a node inside myNode (that it's inside a CDATA) using Simple HTML DOM?

Is it possible, or maybe I should change to another lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDATA blocks will be ignored by any parser, so any xml nodes that you have in CDATA blocks will not be queryable unless you parse the CDATA text as well.  In other words:

1. Parse your original document
2. Query your CDATA text block.  You will get a new xml string.
3. Parse your new (inner) xml string, and query whatever data you need from it.

Having said all of that, why in the world do you have full xml text inside of CDATA blocks?  Sounds like extremely lazy escaping to me.

Comment: Well, the XML it's not mine. I'm working with a scrapper and I cannot modify the XML.

Comment: Got it.  Don't you hate having to hack your code to work around other people's issues?

Comment: Well, I preferer to think as a challenge :P

Comment: Not accurate, `$e->xmltext` added in V 1.11 (2008-12-14) returns the CDATA as text